# Program for separating connections for different program traffic?

Tags: networking, internet, home-networking, internet-connection, network-adapter

I have seen that for combining 2 different connections into one for gaining speed you have to set up routers and flash their memory or buy new ones, and that's the only way for combining it by hardware.
But is there a **program**, that can be connected to one connection and set internet to one programs, and other connection to different programs?
I'm looking for a simple solution :)

Thank you!

Update:
I found [Connectify Dispatch](http://www.connectify.me/dispatch/), but it's expensive, any freeware or less expensive solution?

Comment: What do you mean? If you connect to one connection, how would you possibly have different programs on different connections?

Comment: I meant if you use one connection for one program ( one ISP, for example on your wired connection for torrents ) and one connection for other program (for example, wireless, different ISP and for Google Chrome )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had originally answered with a link to [Connectify Disdpatch](http://www.connectify.me/dispatch) but then realized that does the opposite of what you want. It combines different connections into one.

There is a program called [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) that does what you are looking for. From that page:

> ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows application that will inject itself
> into another application and alter how certain Windows Sockets calls
> are made, allowing you to force the other application to use a
> specific network interface / IP address. This is useful if you are in
> an environment with multiple interfaces and your application has no
> such option for binding to a specific interface.
>
> ...
>
> Some programs that have been tested to work with ForceBindIP include
> DC++, uTorrent, Quake II, Quake III, Diablo II, StarCraft, Internet
> Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Google Earth, Infantry, Real Player, Unreal
> Tournament 2004 (requires -i), Outlook 2000 (requires -i). Programs
> that do not work include GetRight (anti-debugger / forking
> techniques), WinCVS (forks cvs.exe)

It only works on 32-bit Windows systems so that might be an issue for you.